# Value cast vs Reference cast

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the difference between *value cast* and *reference cast*? Why one of them invokes conversion (aka creating new object) and other doesn't? What are caveats of using casting on rhs?

Assume *this* is *Derived* . Why those will not actually cast to *Base*?

```
*this = (Base&) rhs
(Base)* this = rhs
```

Could you please show on simple examples?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by the two assignments?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , casting to Base

Comment: I am talking about the assignments, not the castings. What is the end goal of assigning `*this` the value of `rhs` after casting it to `Base&`?

Comment: So, rhs is Derived, I want to assign all inherited and noninherited stuff from rhs into Base. And the goal is not that important. 1st line will return error, why? 2nd line actually has no sense unless we do (Base&), why? I'm not trying to fix above code, I'm trying to understand why above code is garbage and useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value cast creates a new value from an existing one; reference cast creates a new reference to the same existing value.

Reference cast neither changes the content of an existing object nor creates a new one; it is restricted to changing the interpretation of the value that is already there. Value casting, on the other hand, can make a new object from an existing one, so it has fewer restrictions.

For example, if you have an `unsigned char` and you want a value or a reference of type `int`, value cast is going to work, while reference casting is going to fail:

```
unsigned char orig = 'x';
int  v(orig); // Works
int &r(orig); // Does not work
```

> `rhs` is `Derived`, I want to assign all inherited and non-inherited stuff from `rhs` into `Base`

Then you need to cast both sides to `Base`, or add an assignment operator to `Derived` that takes a `const Base&` as an argument. Here is an example of casting on both sides (may be hard to understand by other programmers reading your code)

```
struct Base {
    int x;
    Base(int x) : x(x) {}
};
struct Derived1 : public Base {
    Derived1(int x) : Base(x) {}
};
struct Derived2 : public Base {
    Derived2(int x) : Base(x) {}
};
```

Running the code below

```
Derived1 d1(5);
Derived2 d2(10);
cout << d1.x << " " << d2.x << endl;
((Base&)d1) = (Base&)d2;
cout << d1.x << " " << d2.x << endl;
```

produces the following printout:

```
5 10
10 10
```

As you can see, the assignment `((Base&)d1) = (Base&)d2` copied the content of `d2`'s `Base` portion into `d1`'s `Base` portion ([demo](https://ideone.com/htrkPk)).

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between value cast and reference cast?

Value casts convert an object to the value:

```
char i = 'a';
int  k = static_cast<int>(i);  // Prefer C++ casts to C casts
```

Reference casts convert an object to a reference:

```
char i = 'a';
int &k = static_cast<int&>(i);
```

Just because the conversion can be done implicitly in `int &k = i` doesn't mean it doesn't happen.

> Why one of them invokes conversion (aka creating new object) and other doesn't?

If you write `int &x = static_cast<int&>(i)`, there are 2 things that can happen:

1) A pointer is created pointing to `i` (references are hidden pointers). Then this *hidden pointer* gets assigned to `x`, and `x` behaves as a reference of `i`.

2) Usually, the compiler optimizes away this reference, and simply considers x an **alias** of i. Therefore no variable is instantiated.

In the former case, a new object is created.

However, if you write:

```
char c = 'a';
int  i = static_cast<int> (c);
```

there is no instantiation, just a copy of the memory from `c` to `i`.

> Why those will not actually cast to Base?

```
*this = (Base&) rhs
```

You cannot assign the **base object** to a **derived object**, only the opposite. This will most likely overwrite the fields of the **base object** to the **derived object's**.

```
(Base)* this = rhs
```

There is no point in castling an **l-value**. This is equivalent to:

```
*this = rhs;
```

> What are caveats of using casting on rhs?

I don't think there is anything wrong with casting, as long as they do not decrease readability.

Comment: `The cast itself does not invoke creating any object, the assignment does.` not true. Casting will invoke the conversion operator, and yeild a prvalue of the converted type. The assignment simply construct that object in place into the variable.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot. You are right, I think I didn't express myself accurately (as this will be optimized). I'm fixing it now